# Importing javascript file from secondary folder into jsf contex

Tags: javascript, jsf

I'm using a a javascript library in a JSF 2.1 project and I have the next hierachy in the resources folder:

```
-resources
  -js
    -controls
      -simpleControl.js
```

The problem is that I can only import js files when they are just in the js folder but I don't know how I can import them if they are in a folder inside the js folder. I already tried the next lines and none of them worked:

```
<h:outputScript library="js/controls" name="simpleControl.js"/>
<h:outputScript library="js" name="controls/simpleControl.js"/>
<h:outputScript name="js/controls/simpleControl.js"/>
<script name="js/controls/simpleControl.js"/>
<script name="controls/simpleControl.js?ln=js"/>
<script name="simpleControl.js?ln=js/controls"/>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried this way "<script src="#{resource['js/controls/simpleControl.js']}">" ?

Comment: Apparently the JS file in question isn't properly been deployed. Just clean/rebuild/redeploy/restart and doublecheck the contents of the deployed WAR file. The `<h:outputScript name="js/controls/simpleControl.js"/>` is the right one. The former two are functionally also correct, but semantically not. The last three are apart from the wrong attribute (it must be `src`) error prone in paths as they are relative to request URI instead of context path.

Comment: Thanks BalusC! It works with <h:outputScript name="js/controls/simpleControl.js"/> after cleaning!